# the numer of partial function between two sets in combinatoric way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$A$ and $B$ two sets. $|A|=k, |B|=n.$ I need to prove in a combinatoric way that the number of partial function from $A$ to $B$ is $(n+1)^k.$ I thing the number is $Σ(n^i),$ for $i=0$ to $k.$ but I have no idea how to show equality, and how to prove it in
a combinatoric way.

If someone can show me the way or guide me that will be great!

thanks for helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $p$ be some object not in $B$, and let $B'=B\cup\{p\}$.

- Explain why there are $(n+1)^k$ functions from $A$ to $B'$.
- Find a bijection between the set of partial functions from $A$ to $B$ and the set of total functions from $A$ to $B'$. (Think about how you might interpret $f(a)=p$ if yo want to convert the function $f:A\to B'$ into a partial function from $A$ to $B$.)

Comment: thanks. What you wrote above consider to be a combinatoric solution?

Comment: @joe: Yes, it would. You're welcome.

Comment: I cant find a bijection

Comment: @joe: Suppose that $g$ is the partial function corresponding to $f:A\to B'$. Think of $f(a)=p$ as meaning that $a$ is not in the domain of $g$. Can you see now how to describe $g$ in terms of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider any $C \subseteq A$. If $i = |C|$, then $ 0 \leq i \leq k$, because $|A| = k$. There are exactly $k \choose i$ subsets $C$ of $A$, such that $|C| = i$. This means that there are exactly $n^i \cdot {{k} \choose {i}}$ functions from $C$ into $B$. So there are

$$
\sum_{i=0}^k n^i {k \choose i} = (1+n)^k
$$

functions from all the subsets of $A$ into $B$.