# count the numer of partial function between two sets with bijection

Tags: combinatorics, functions

A and B two sets. |A|=k,|B|=n. prove: the number of partial function from A to B is (n+1)^k.
proof:
x-object not in B.
B*=BUx.

The total function (not partial) between A and B* is (n+1)^k.
Now I need to find a bijection between the set of all partial function from A to B and the set of all function between A and B*.

someone can show me please explicit bijection that would do the work

thanks.

Comment: You already asked that question and got answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599311/the-numer-of-partial-function-between-two-sets-in-combinatoric-way/1599346#1599346

Comment: Hint:  if $f: A\to B$ is a partial function, define a true function $\hat f: A\to B^*$ by $\hat f(a)=f(a)$ if $f(a)$ is defined and $\hat f(a)=x$ otherwise.

Comment: I note that  (unsurprisingly) my comment is more or less identical to the arguments given in the earlier version of this question.  If there is some part of those answers you don't understand, you ask about them specifically.

Comment: It is really hard from to understand can you show me?

Comment: The idea is extremely simple (though writing it out can muddy the waters a bit).  The idea is this:  A partial function is just a regular function defined on a subset.  That is we have $f:A_1\to B$ where $A_1\subseteq A$.  Let $A_2$ be the complement of $A_1$ in $A$.  We can then extend $f$ to a true function, $\hat f$ on $A$, with values in $B^*$ by defining $\hat f=f$ on $A_1$ and $\hat f (a)=x \;\forall a\in A_2$.  That is, instead of saying that $f$ is "undefined" on $A_2$ we simply declare that it sends all of $A_2$ to the special value $x$.

Comment: If you are still confused, I suggest writing it out in detail for a small example.  Suppose, say, that both $A$ and $B$ have two elements.  If that example is too easy, make increase the size of $A$ or $B$ or both.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: An element of $A$ can go to any element of $B$, or it can be unmapped.